# regex + select everything but word1 or word2

Tags: regex

here is my [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/Sruubs/1)

I can select Apple or Orange with `Apple|Orange`

```
Apple
Orange 
Banana
Peanut
Strawberry
```

How do I select everything but Apple or Orange. I have tried this character `^` but cant seem to get it

Comment: don't put text on external link. Please edit the question and put it here

Comment: if this is off topic `This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.` can people please suggest a more suitable place where I could post the Q.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is use of `negative lookahead/lookbehind`, but it may be too complicated/overhead for your case. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: it's off-topic because `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`, not because it `does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center`. You need to include the code/regex here, not on external sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try negative lookahead:

```
(?!Apple|Orange)\b\w+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Sruubs/2

Documentation: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html